# The inputs do not show me the data passed from another window

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am passing parameters from one window to another but my html is not specifically read by the `<ion-input>`
But if in my `<ion-card-header>`, someone knows why this happens
As you can see in the picture.
The data that happens if it shows in the `<ion-card-header>` but not in the `<ion-input>`.

As you can see in the ioni-car part, if the data is shown:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="userReady">
        <ion-card-header> {{ user.email }} </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-header> {{ user.name }} </ion-card-header>
    </ion-list>
```

But in input I do not read them:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="userReady">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres"> {{ user.name }}
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
..................
```

[image]

```
<ion-content padding class="body" align="center">
    <img src="assets/logito.png">
    <br>
    <br>

    <ion-list *ngIf="userReady">
        <ion-card-header> {{ user.email }} </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-header> {{ user.name }} </ion-card-header>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list *ngIf="userReady">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres"> {{ user.name }}
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Email"> {{ user.email }}
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input clearInput type="text" placeholder="Teléfono">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="dark" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='checkmark-circle-outline'></ion-icon>
        registar
      </button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set value in ion-input use ngModel,
so change

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres"> {{ user.name }}
</ion-input>
```

to

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
            </ion-input>
```